# c# two parameters in one parameter in a method

Tags: c#, methods, parameters

I would like to make one method like this:

```
public void SomeMethod(int myInt,<float or double or MyClass> myFloatorDoubleorMyClass)
{

}
```

And not only with generics, but also with any class.
I would like to avoid this:

```
public void SomeMethod(int myInt, float myFloat)
{

}

public void SomeMethod(int myInt, double myFloat)
{

}

public void SomeMethod(int myInt, MyClass myClass)
{

}
```

Is this feasible?

Comment: Yes. `SomeMethod<T>(int myInt, T myFloatorDouble) where T : unmanaged`
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/unmanaged-types)

Comment: You could use overloads, but is it really useful to make the distinction?

Comment: @Fildor what do you mean by overloads?

Comment: See [Member overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/member-overloading)

Comment: _"And not only with generics, but also with any class."_ - I do not understand this. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Fildor In c# i met with errors that said i can't cast **T** to a non generic type. Like in wpf _DependencyObject_.

Comment: You really should consider rephrasing the question to actual DependencyObjects. It's a whole different story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achive this with [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics)

Could look like

```
public void SomeMethod<T>(int myInt, T myFloatorDouble)
{

}
```

But it could be cleaner with overloads like

```
public void SomeMethod(int myInt, float myFloat)
{

}

public void SomeMethod(int myInt, double myDouble)
{

}
```

Depends on the logic in your method. If you have to cast inside the method, I would recommend overloads for example.

Comment: Would definitely not recommend generics for this, creates more problems than it solves. Overloads are 100% the way to go.

Comment: The problem with Generics: I could also do `SomeMethod<object>( 5, new object() );`. (Among other issues for this specific case)

Comment: @Fildor Can u name some issues with this, becouse in my point of view, it could be good.

Comment: Well, what do you win? Now you have a generic type T, of which you know nothing. What are you going to do with it? Do _a lot_ of "if ( myGeneric is double d) {...}" ?

Comment: My target is to make a method in c# wpf where i can get the DependencyObject margin, but with the DependencyObject class, i can't do it. But i have a lot of dependencyobject, like Label, TextBox, CheckBox, etc. So i would like to make a method where no mather what dependencyobject (or some of them) i give, a culd get the margin, or other parameters, what any dependency object have.

Comment: System.Windows.DependencyObject or Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject?

Comment: System.Windows.DependencyObject

Comment: But actually, this makes this a whole different Question. It's really x-y. I haven't had a deep dive in WPF for some years, but you definitely can get DependencyProperty Values from DependencyObjects.

Comment: When i tried in different ways, i couldn't figure out how, but that just one method where i would use the mensioned method in above. But you helped me a lot anyway, so thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use overloading like this:

```
public void SomeMethod(int myInt, double myDouble)
{
   // ...
}

public void SomeMethod(int myInt, float myFloat)
{
   SomeMethod(myInt, (double)myFloat);
}
```

Note that this is valid because a `float` can be put into a `double` without loosing precision.

**Update:** The question was updated, and specifically requests to avoid overloading. In this case my answer above is no longer relevant. I still believe (as others who commented on this post) that overloading in this case is prefered over the alternative (using generics).

BTW - In this specific case a `float` can be automatically converted to a `double`. But using overloading is a good solution also when you have types that do not convert automatically.

Comment: That's what i want to avoid, becouse i have to make a lot of methods this way.

Comment: The  other option is to use generics, but as you can see in other comments for your post it is not recomended (at least for this case).

Comment: _"becouse i have to make a lot of methods this way"_ I actually still do not see why. You can perfectly put a float into a double method parameter.

Comment: @Fildor The method in the post was just an example. I would like to use it with a lot of parameters.

Comment: A lot of parameters or a lot of parameter types? Maybe add some more xamples to your question. I don't think it is at all clear what you are going for.

Comment: Like Label, TextBox, CheckBox, etc. WPF DependencyObjects, but i expressed it in a lower comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void SomeMethod(int myInt, object value)
    {
        if (value == null) { throw new Exception("exception"); }
        else
        {
            var typecode = Convert.GetTypeCode(value);
            if (typecode == TypeCode.Object && value.GetType().IsClass && value.GetType().Name == nameof(MyClass)) { var result = (MyClass)value; }
            else if (typecode == TypeCode.Double) { var result = Convert.ToDouble(value); }
            else if (typecode == TypeCode.Single) { var result = Convert.ToSingle(value); }
            else { throw new NotImplementedException("exception"); }
        }
    }
```